# How to append to Path environment variable with a script

Tags: windows, batch-file

In windows, i would like to append two folders to my path variable using a .bat file.

All i got is:

`setx Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" /m
pause`

But this command completely override my path variable.

Comment: `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" /m`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, you are overwriting Path and you need to append to the path.  Try:

```
setx Path "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" /m
pause
```

This will add your new folders to the end of the existing path .

Steve

Comment: You'll need to insert a `;` to separate the paths -- see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319966/how-to-append-to-path-environment-variable-with-a-script#comment60263282_36319966)...